# French Citizenship through Parent

Tags: citizenship

So I am American and was born in Atlanta, GA... my father during my birth was French Citizen living in America... After I was born he registered my birth with France (so he says). Going off the website of the French Government, they say you are French if one of your parents was french at the MOMENT you were born. And my father was French the moment I was born and only had a green card (for USA). So since he registered my birth, what do I do now to get my citizenship? am i already a citizen when he registered it? or what? can i now get my French passport? Do i need to send in documents or anything to the French Embassy/ Consulate? I CANNOT find ANY information online on what the heck I have to do since I am registered. Can I call someone to check and see if I was registered with France when I was born to make sure of it?

Comment: Start by reading: [Civil registry and nationality - France in the Southeast region](https://atlanta.consulfrance.org/spip.php?article5205) ; Check with them if your father registered you. A copy of your birth certificate and your fathers french passport will probably be needed if not.

Answer (score 3):

> So since he registered my birth, what do I do now to get my citizenship?

Probably nothing, from what you've told us, perhaps unless you're over 50.  (There's a fifty-year rule that I don't understand very well.)

> Am i already a citizen when he registered it? or what? can i now get my French passport?

Yes.  You're probably a French citizen and you can apply for a passport.

> Do i need to send in documents or anything to the French Embassy/ Consulate?

Of course.  Passport applications always require documents.  The link for the relevant page in English yields a 404 error, but there's plenty of [information in French](https://atlanta.consulfrance.org/spip.php?article5764) including a list of the documents required for a [first passport application when the applicant is an adult](https://atlanta.consulfrance.org/spip.php?article5766).

Comment: I second @phoog's answer. If your father registered your birth with the consulate, you should be French by birth. If so, you can apply for a passport at the consulate and see if it goes through (see the links phoog posted). They might ask for a copy of your father's birth certificate and possibly his ID/passport to further prove his nationality. 

In case you run into issues (e.g. they deny your passport application), the only way to prove you already have French nationality is to apply for a ["certificat de nationalité française"](https://washington.consulfrance.org/spip.php?article974)

Comment: I have acquired my French Passport. My father had all the documents for when he registered me at birth with France. All good. Thank you.